# How to stop a process after you run it?

Tags: c#

This is the code I used to run the following exe program. How can I end this 3 process after I had run it?

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Bot-shortcut\DIE1.exe");
Process.Start(@"C:\Bot-shortcut\DIE2.exe");
Process.Start(@"C:\Bot-shortcut\DIE3.exe");
```

Answer (score 6):

First, store the process object returned when you start the process.

If you want it to close *normally*, as though someone had clicked the close icon, then use `CloseMainWindow`.  This simulates clicking the close icon so that the process can shut down normally. This is always preferable to killing the process, which can corrupt data.

If you want it to die instantly then use `Kill`. Note that this can corrupt data; the process might have been writing to a file when you killed it.

Comment: Thumbs up if you like Eric's new picture `:)`

Comment: @SonerGönül: Looks younger, no more a [serious-author-face](http://ericlippert.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/EricLippertHeadshot.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the process by Name and then stop it.
Here is the code snippet from MSDN:

```
 Process[] myProcesses;
    // Returns array containing all instances of Notepad.
    myProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
    foreach (Process myProcess in myProcesses)
    {
        myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
    }
```

The Process.kill() will also stop the process but without any prompt.

Find the details in [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05abh773%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) article.

Comment: Why would you get the process by name if you're the one who started it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can end your process using [Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx)

```
Process myProcess =  new Process(@"C:\Bot-shortcut\DIE1.exe");

myProcess.Start();

//After Some Codes

myProcess.Kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start returns the process instance which you have started.

Store that in variable and use [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) method to kill that process once you are done with it.

```
Process process = Process.Start(@"C:\Bot-shortcut\DIE1.exe");
process.Kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the process objects as variables:

```
var proc1 =Process.Start(@"C:\Bot-shortcut\DIE1.exe");
var proc2 = Process.Start(@"C:\Bot-shortcut\DIE2.exe");
var proc3 = Process.Start(@"C:\Bot-shortcut\DIE3.exe");
```

And wait for them to exit:

```
proc1.WaitForExit();
proc2.WaitForExit();
proc3.WaitForExit();
```

Or kill them:

```
proc1.Kill();
proc2.Kill();
proc3.Kill();
```